# How do I add a delay between each iteration of a for of or forEach loop over Set elements?

Tags: javascript, async-await, settimeout, setinterval, ws

I have a function like shown below where websocketServer.clients basically contains a Set of websocket objects. The setInterval causes my server to get spikes and I would like to basically terminate inactive clients one by one with a small delay in between in a more uniform manner. Both forEach and for of loops run instantaneously, how do I add a delay between them to replicate the same functionality without using a setInterval?

```
export function terminateIdleConnections() {
  const interval = setInterval(function ping() {
    console.log('entry', new Date());
    websocketServer.clients.forEach(function each(ws) {
      // @ts-ignore
      if (ws.isAlive === false) {
        console.log('terminating connection', new Date());
        return ws.terminate();
      } else {
        console.log('pinging connection', new Date());
        // @ts-ignore
        ws.isAlive = false;
        ws.ping();
      }
    });
  }, WEBSOCKET_CHECK_IDLE_CONNECTION_FREQUENCY);

  websocketServer.on('close', function close() {
    console.log('terminating INTERVAL', new Date());
    clearInterval(interval);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that's a weird approach, but what if you try to implement this with `setTimeout`? You'd need to initiate another `setTimeout` with each function call, so the next function activity is rescheduled.

Unluckily I have no setup available to try this approach.

`setInterval` and `setTimeout` are the only JavaScript approaches I know to delay code execution. Afaik every alternative implementation runs back to these functions, or burns cpu time by looping until a certain date/time is reached.